# Apple Magic Keyboard along ubuntu mate and VNC

Tags: keyboard, vnc, mate

Normally, i access my ubuntu server 22.04 via ssh terminal. Now, i need a graphical interface and installing ubuntu mate and tigervnc server. It works so fare.

I can select the Apple Keyboard (MacBook Pro intl.) in the Mate control center, use "show" for checking and, for example "@" sign, seems to be OK.

But outside the control center, X-Termimal or Mate-Terminal, no "@"-sign can be used.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key combination Control & Command & "L" gives "@" too.

Comment: Is this an answer? It's not clear to me..

Comment: Yes. In my case this key combination gives a @ sign with a  apple magic keyboard used to access ubuntu mate desktop on a headless, vnc connected ubuntu machine.